# Would Servlet 3 annotations enable secret backdoor access?

Tags: java, servlets, annotations

I hope people don't mind me asking a question which is slightly future gazing.  Please forgive me if my understanding is incorrect (and please put me right!).  **Servlet 3** introduces several new annotations including:

***@WebServlet***

***@WebFilter***

***@WebListener***

and also a something called **web-fragment.xml**.  These all seem to be aimed at making it possible to deploy servlets, filters and listeners without having to edit web.xml.

Does that mean that if I included a JAR file from an unscrupulous provider that they could surface servlets, filters and listeners in my web applications without my knowledge?

Comment: The last two annotation names are wrong. You can find them all here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html

Comment: @BalusC: seems like there's plenty outdated/wrong info still floating around w/r/t what these things are actually called. Ex.: http://www.javabeat.net/articles/97-new-features-in-servlets-30-1.html - pretty high up in the Google results for _"java filter annotation"_

Comment: @Matt: javabeat.net .. Don't talk me about it. It's almost in the same category as [roseindia.net](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html) (cry). Only thing which they can do very good is SEO. The concrete content is generally poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They could, but the issue here is not in the specification: it's in running untrusted code. If you allow a jar that you don't trust to load and run, then it could potentially do things that are a lot worse than surfacing a servlet.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, maybe not.  (I don't know for sure).  But if you are worried about things that unscrupulous providers might do in their JARs, there are a whole bunch of other nasty things they could do in plain old Java.  If you are worried about this kind of thing, you really need to insist on getting source code, and you need to do a thorough audit of the code before you let it onto your production servers.

Comment: Agreed. What's stopping any JAR from opening a socket and providing a backdoor? Or even injecting a virus in the system! This doesn't have to be web server.

Comment: Nothing, but any reasonable firewall would prevent anything to connect to a separate listening socket or the malicious JAR to make any unexpected outbound network connections. If the malicious JAR is allowed to add servlet filters, it can hook itself into the processing chain of any HTTP request and provide a backdoor through obviously sane and expected HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `<absolute-ordering>` element in the main web.xml deployment descriptor to list only the jar files in WEB-INF/lib, which you want to be automatically analyzed for annotations and web-fragment.xml descriptors during deployment.

If you do so, the content of web-fragments or annotated classes in other JAR files are not deployed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to control this process, quote from [here](http://ttp://www.javabeat.net/articles/print.php?article_id=97):

> The Servlet 3.0 specification also
>   provides an option for instructing the
>   Web Container, whether the container
>   should process the annotations defined
>   on the web components. The name of the
>   element is metadata-complete and it is
>   a child element of web-app element.
>   The metadata-complete  element
>   indicates whether the meta-data
>   information available in the
>   deployment descriptor is complete. So,
>   if the value for the metadata-complete
>   element is set to a value of true,
>   then it means that the meta
>   information found in the deployment
>   descriptor is complete and eventually
>   the annotations defined on the web
>   components will be ignored by the
>   Servlet Container. If the value for
>   metadata-complete  is set to false,
>   then it means that the information in
>   the deployment descriptor is not
>   complete and web components decorated
>   with annotations, if any, should be
>   scanned and processed by the Web
>   Container.